# Geometry nodes: face average color from image in blender 4

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I have a problem finding a way to replicate averaging face color sampled from image in geometry nodes (Blender > 3.5 or Blender 4) as in the example below[image]

All videos I found on YT are about averaging the color for instances but no one is showing how to do this if you are not using instances - for example:

You add geo nodes to a plane with material that has uv image on it.
Then in geo nodes, you add the grid, separate its edges, and scale down the elements to get islands of separated faces.
I would like to apply the average color to each one of them based on the location in relation to the original image that is in the material of original geometry (plane).

Comment: I don't understand how this Blender 2.9x example works. Are there cuts in the plane? Why is the 2nd face in the top left corner greyish? In the image there is a lot of red color in this area. The 4th face is quite dark. Why is the Vertex Color "Col" used as a UV map in the shader? How is the "average" color created? It looks like that a color is picked (from the face?) and assigned it to all face corners of that face.

Answer (score 1):

with this setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly the same answer as Chris, but avoids the blur effect by just changing the domain to "face" in the capture attribute node:

[image]

This is not a real average (whatever the solution is: I don't think it's possible to completely sample the texture surface), but based on vertex UV positions.